# FlatList onPress should navigate to new page (details of the clicked item)

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I would like to write a code when Flatlist onPress should navigate to new page and open details of the content. Can anyone help me out in writing code for navigating and open it in EventContent page

I have written a bit of code to navigate to new page when on press. But I am unable to find out the right solution and open the content in new page called EventContent page. I am new to react native can anyone help me out in getting the solution.

App.js

```
detail:{
 screen: EventContent,
 navigationOptions:()=>({
   title:'',
 })
},
```

EventCard where I have added my  to navigate new page. I am unable to write the proper code to navigate next page and open the content in detail.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        flex: 1,
        padding:10,
        paddingTop:10,
        paddingBottom:10,
        margin:10,
        marginTop:10,
        marginBottom:5,
        borderColor:'#000'

    },
    cardHeader:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'row'
    },
    date:{
        fontWeight:'200',
        fontSize:15,
        color:'#bdbdbd',
        width:'30%',
        textAlign:'left',
    },
    title:{
        fontSize:20,
        fontWeight:'200',
        marginLeft:7,
        textAlign:'left',
    },
    counterContainer:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:'space-between',
        paddingLeft:'5%',
        paddingRight:'5%',
    },
    counter:{
        width:'25%',
        flex:1,
    },
    counterText:{
        fontSize:15,
        textAlign:'justify',
        color:"#A8A4A4",
    },
    counterLabel:{
        fontSize:13,
        fontWeight:'100',
        color:'#a3a3a3',
        textAlign:'justify',
        paddingTop:0,
    },
});

export default function EventCard({ events }) {

    var currentDate = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('detail')}>,
        <View style={styles.card}>
        <View style={styles.cardHeader}>
                <Text style={styles.date}>{(currentDate)}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.title}> {events.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.counterContainer}>
                <View style={styles.counter}>
                    <Text style={styles.counterText}>{events.content}</Text>

                </View>
            </View>
        </View>

        </TouchableOpacity>

    );
}

EventCard.propTypes = {
    event: PropTypes.shape({
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        date: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date)
    }),
};

EventList where my FlatList Content is returned. Can anyone direct me whether I am going in the right path or have to change any content in the code.


 class EventList extends Component {
  state = {
    events: [],
  }
 componentDidMount() {

     //getEvents().then(events => this.setState({ events }));

    const events = require('./db.json').events;
    this.setState({ events });

  }
render() {
    return [

      <FlatList
        key="flatlist"
        style={styles.list}
        data={this.state.events}
        renderItem={({ item, seperators }) => (<EventCard events={item} />)}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

      />,
```

EventContent In this page I need to write the code to open the content in detail and able to edit the content.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,
Text,
View,
} from 'react-native';
import EventCard from './EventCard';
import EventList from './EventList';

const { navigation } = this.props;
const itemId = navigation.getParam(' ', ' ');


return (
    <View 
       style={{ 
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center' 
        }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    </View>
);
```

When onPress should navigate to EventContent page and open the content in detail to edit or view the content.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EventCard` should have access to the `navigation` prop in order to navigate to the specific route in your navigator. From the code, it seems that you are on right direction except that your `EventCard` doesn't have access to the `navigation` prop. To do so, pass that up as a prop as well like below.

```
renderItem={({ item, seperators }) => (<EventCard navigation={this.props.navigation} events={item} />)}
```

and then you should be accessing the navigation from the props being given to the `EventCard` like this:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('detail')}>
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion and code. Sir a small doubt how to retrieve one flatlist event when onPress it should navigate to EventDetails and have to open the event details which is been clicked. Thank you once again sir. @SurajMalviya

Comment: Hi, @SurajMalviya I am getting error as navigation is not defined. If I add the renderItem and TouchableOpacity within EventCard.js file.

Comment: So the problem is you don't have `navigation` in your `EventCard`, please pass it as a prop from `EventList` if you are rendering `EventCard` inside `EventList`.

Comment: I am unable to add the navigation props in EventCard and its showing multiple errors. Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: Can anyone post the code of navigation when on Press should open the flatlist details in new page